# Screen Name of followers Twitter

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I'm using package `rtweet`. I would like to obtain a list of user `screenName` for accounts following a specified user. I used `get_followers` but it returned a list of user IDs. Is there a fast way to convert each of these IDs to its corresponding screenName?

Comment: `lookup_users(your_data$user_id)$screen_name` ?

Comment: @bouncyball: it works! Thank you